# Google Plus get notification of a friend activity similarly to Close Friend list in facebook

Tags: facebook, google-plus, notifications, list

When I want to see updates of a friend in Google Plus, I currently have to go to his home page to see them - while in facebook, what I need to do is to add him/her to my `Close Friend` list.

Is there a similar feature in Google Plus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much similar, yes. You could easily add your friend to a circle.

Click on that circle, and set the slider in the top right corner to *Show all posts from [circle name] on your start page*.

Then, all posts from friends you have added to the circle will show up in your start page stream.

[image]

Comment: @nam-g-vu, thanks for adding the screenshot! However, in your screenshot, you have dragged the slider all the way to the right (to "Get notification for the selected circle"), while in my answer I suggest setting it at "Show all posts from ... on your start page" (the fourth option). Could you replace your screenshot with one that displays this setting?

Comment: The exact setting depends on exactly what you really want. The original question said "get notifications", which would be the rightmost setting on the slider, and it will both appear on your home stream as well as send you an email/notification when they post. If you just want to guarantee it will appear on your home stream, the setting right next to it is correct.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal I agree with user `Prisoner`. My OP is about getting notification so the rightmous setting is the correct one

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Today I go to `Circles` and select a circle, the slide-bar you mentioned has disappeared. Do you see the same thing in your plus circles page?

Comment: When I go to the start page (https://plus.google.com/), select a cricle from the buttons on the top, I can still see the slide bar. (Note: I don't click the "Circles" button in the left hand toolbar)